# total number of formulas in workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

My operating system is macOS mojave v10.14.4.
My excel version is mac excel 16.23 (190309).
How do I count total number of formulas in workbook (not worksheet...) without using VBA?
I have searched on Google and in Superuser with no luck.

Comment: There is an ISFORMULA function that returns true if the cell contains a formula.  You could try doing a COUNTIF, testing the entire workbook against that criterion.  The number of worksheets might dictate the practicality of doing it without VBA.  (And the cell with the count is an extra formula cell, so subtract 1.)  :-)

Comment: Better question is how do you make it non circular?

Comment: Count formula in entire workbook is only possible using VBA (Macro),, a formula can count also but problem is variable sheet and huge cell references !!

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

If you just want a quick count cells with formulas

1. Select All your worksheets
2. Select Goto (F5 on Windows)
3. Select Special then formulas, then OK

In the bottom of the screen you will get a count of cell with formulas in them.